# Only run code if body has class of X?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want this code to only run if the body has a class of `home`. So I've created a variable called `isHome` and I'm trying to wrap the code around it. However, I think there's something wrong with the code. Can someone point out what is wrong?

```
var isHome = $('body.home');

if (isHome) {
    $('.wp-polls-form input.Buttons').click(function( e ){
        e.preventDefault();
        $('html, body').animate({
            scrollTop: $("#top-section").offset().top - (
              $(window).width() < 450 ? 112 : 60
            )
        }, 500);
    });
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your if condition will always be true because a jQuery object, even if it's empty, will equate to `true`.

Instead, you can use the `length` property to check if a selector found a match:

```
var $isHome = $('body.home');
if ($isHome.length) {
    // your code...
}
```

Or you can use `hasClass` to check if the element has the required class:

```
if ($('body').hasClass('home')) {
    // your code...
}
```

Comment: In what way does it check if a selector found a match?

Comment: @J82 the length property contains the number of elements the selector matched. Because `0` will be cast as false you can use the above in an if statement to test if any elements were found.

Answer (score 3):

Use as

```
if($('body').hasClass("home"))
```

Answer (score 2):

Use `.hasClass()` as shown:

```
var isHome = $('body').hasClass('home');
```

If **body has a class home** then **$('body').hasClass('home');** statement will **return true** otherwise **false**.

Or directly use `if($('body').hasClass("home"))`

Answer (score 0):

you should try `.hasClass()` as it returns `boolean`

```
   var isHome = $('body').hasClass('home');
   if(isHome) { //your code }
```

Thanks !!